# twitter_time does not gives follower_count for retweet user

Tags: twitter

I am using `twitter_timeline` to get the user details.

It provides set of tweets including RTs. I am considering on retweets from all tweets.

Suppose I retweeted any tweet, which I can get using:

```
$tweets3 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?trim_user=true&include_rts=true");

 foreach ($tweets3 as $item)
        {
                $rt_reach =  $item->retweet_count; //This is available
                $text = $item->text; //This is available

                $follower_count = $item->user->followers_count; //This is not available
                echo "User location $item->user->location"; //This is not available
                echo  $follower_count = $item->user->screen_name; //This is not available
        }
```

Link to document: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Why it does not provide last three value in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using "trim_user=true", twitter strips the user record except for the user_id. 
Please check trim_user parameter [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

The "trim_user" param is used by applications to stop the tweets data from getting bloated and it should be excluded if the app needs the full user record, which seems to be the case for you.

Comment: thanks, but `trim_user=true` strips the record which belongs to user_id. I think it is opposite to what you said

Comment: That's what I said but maybe I didn't say it properly. trim_user will only return the user_id of the tweet creator and strip all other info about the tweeting user.

Comment: Also, it seems like you want the info for the original tweeter and not the retweeter. Is that accurate? For that you need to look inside the "retweeted_status" item, which contains the original tweet object and look for the user object inside that tweet object for the original tweet creator.

Comment: In either case, you have to remove the trim_user param or set it to false.

Comment: any contact for you? I have one more doubt in twitter apis @Vishal

Comment: Sure, feel free to email at mishravishal@gmail.com

Comment: can you please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663696/getting-retweet-reach-by-user-retweet-values